# Could not open file archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_eoan-updates_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, update-manager, 19.10

Greetings from Bangladesh. I am an intermediate user of Ubuntu OS. I am facing problem with apt update. I have searched online but could not find any answer to my problem so I am posting this question please help me.

```
Err:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_eoan-updates_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Err:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_eoan-backports_main_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-updates/restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_eoan-updates_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-backports/main/cnf/Commands-amd64  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_eoan-backports_main_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried with

> 1. removing partial folder's content completely.
> 2. Cleaning apt by `sudo apt clean`
>      `moving the lists to lists.old`
>      `then updating the apt`

But without luck.

Comment: `ping -c4 archive.ubuntu.com` please.

Comment: Ubuntu : There is no `apt update` ... There is `sudo apt update`.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I mean ```sudo apt update```

Comment: @nobody I have pinged successfully. No problem with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the restricted software sources from the list and done a update via `sudo apt update` then again added the restricted software sources to the list and again done another update and the error is gone.